# Integer Solutions of $x+y^n = y + x^m$ for $n < m$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I found 8 of them and believe there is no more:

$$2+3^2=3+2^3$$
$$2+6^2=6+2^5$$
$$6+15^2=15+6^3$$
$$3+16^2=16+3^5$$
$$3+13^3=13+3^7$$
$$2+91^2=91+2^{13}$$
$$5+280^2=280+5^7$$
$$30+4930^2=4930+30^5$$

I call the solution a principal pipe of order 2. Any idea to attack this equation?

If $n=x=2$, it becomes $2+y^2=y+2^m$. It is Ramanujan and Nagell Equation, and there are only 3 solutions. If $n=2$ and $x \geq 3$, then we can use the similar way to prove that there is no other solution for $x < 10000$ with help of computer.

If $n=3$, and we assume $x$ and $y$ are prime, and $6\mid (m-1)$, then the solution is $3+13^3=13+3^7 = 2200$.

I believe there is no solution for $n>3$. I am particularly interested in solutions that both $x$ and $y$ are odd primes.

Comment: What about $n=1$ or $m=1$? Why do you believe there are no other solutions if $n>1$ and $m>1$? Just because you cannot find them?

Comment: I should add the condition: $n < m$ here. Let

Comment: Let $v = x + y^n = y + x^m$, then I found only 8 solutions for $v < 2^{63}$.

Comment: Such solutions are likely to involve consecutive powers.  You might try looking at results of Pillai.  Ribenboim's book on Catalan's equation has more, but I do not think it has this specific form.

Comment: Most likely that $(n-1)\mid(m-1)$ is true.

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to $x(x^{m-1}-1)=y(y^{n-1}-1)$.  If $p$ is a prime that divides $x-1$, then the $p$-adic valuation of $x(x^{m-1}-1)$ is $v_p(x-1)+v_p(m-1)$.  If $p$ does not divide $x-1$ or $x$, then there are similar but more complicated statements that also involve the order of $x$ modulo $p$.  You could probably get quite far with this kind of analysis.

Comment: Thanks. So far I have: $(n,m) = 1$, $y = \lceil x^{m/n} \rceil$ and $x = \lfloor y^{n/m} \rfloor$

Comment: These are all the solutions with $2 \le n < m \le 200$ and $2 \ge x,y \le 20000$.

Comment: What's a pipe? What's a principal pipe? What's a principal pipe of order 2?

Comment: Let $R$ be a finite set of integers $\geq$ 2 and $v$ be an integer larger than any integer in $R$. The doublet $(v, R)$ is called a pipe if $v-r$ is a product of at least two elements in $R$ (multiplicities are taken into account) for each $r\in R$. We denote this doublet $(v, R)$ as $P(v, R)$ if it is a pipe.

Comment: For pipe $P(v,R)$, the number of elements in $R$ is called order of the pipe $P(v,R)$.

Comment: Pipe $P(v,R)$ is principal if for each $r\in R$, either $r$ does not divide $v$ or 
$(v-r)/r$ is not a product of elements in $R$. For more info, please refer to https://sites.google.com/site/basicpipetheory

Comment: This paper in the Journal of Mathematics from 1993 seems to have a proof: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X83710413

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem was considered in a paper of Mignotte and Petho {Publ. Math. Debrecen 1999) and subsequently in one of mine [Canad. Math. J 2001], where there is a conjecture that the equation $a^x-b^y=c$ has, for fixed positive integers $a, b$ and $c$, with $a, b \geq 2$, at most one solution in positive integer exponents $x$ and $y$, with precisely $11$ exceptions. This is provable if $c$ is suitably large or suitably small, but, as far as I know, is still open in general. This problem arose from four classical papers of Pillai.

Comment: I thought it is a hard question and I am happy to get confirmed from you. This equation may not be completely solved in algebraic number theory since this equation has infinitely many solutions if $x$ and $y$ are fractional.

Comment: For example $$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^b} + \frac{1}{4^b} = \frac{1}{4} + \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^b}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^b}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^b \\
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^b} + \frac{1}{4^b} = \frac{1}{4} + \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^b}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^b}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^b$$ for any $b\geq 3$.

Comment: I can say with some confidence that the fact that I couldn't answer it does not make it a hard question!